# Running devcontainer as local user instead of root

Tags: node.js, vscode-devcontainer

**Environment**: Windows 10 with WSL1 and VSCode.

I have a `.devcontainer.json` with the following content:

```
{
    "name": "my-container",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/typescript-node:0-14",
    "forwardPorts": [3000],
    "postCreateCommand": "bash scripts/install-dev-tools.sh",
    "postStartCommand": "cd volvofinans && yarn install"
}
```

When starting the container it starts as user `root` but I would like to run it with the same user as in Windows/WSL e.g. `my-uid`

How can I do that?

Comment: this is supposed to work with the "remoteUser" parameter.   I've tried setting: `"remoteUser": "${localEnv:USER}"` but it doesn't seem to work.  I am on windows, despite always using the WSL termianls, so I've also tried `"remoteUser": "localEnv:UserName"` and it doesn't work either.  I suspect the UserName is maybe the right path, because that crashed the container.  I'm assuming because I don't have anything creating that user for the container... So I need to handle that with something else...

Comment: Also used containerUser, as well as both of them together.   I still think its a matter of creating the user in the container, which I'm leaning towards doing with a script.  Besides, a run_as.sh script would also work for an ENTRYPOINT for use in pipelines when not working with this interactive, so I am thinking I'll write this to handle both situations....